# Measure users who have not visited a certain page in Data Studio with Google Analytics and User-ID

Tags: google-analytics, google-data-studio

I am trying to measure users with Google Analytics User-ID metrics and Data Studio on how many users have NOT visited a certain blog article. Meaning I could see a list of user ids who have not visited a blog page.

Can you give any help or direction on where to look information about how to implement this and what it requires?

Comment: I believe that Google Analytics considers user ids to be personally identifiable information (PII) and won't ever give you a list of them.   Would you be OK with a count instead?

Comment: Counting would definitely be a start. How would you go about this?